# Is there a way to search all available IMAP folders using Javamail?

Tags: search, imap, jakarta-mail

I am looking for a way to search across all folders (for the given user).

I am aware that the [IMAP SEARCH command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) requires that you select a mailbox to operate on first - scoping the results of the search to that particular mailbox.

The Javamail IMAP implementation implements a `search` function that operates on a `Folder` object. This would appear to mimic the spec, in that it will search within a given folder.

I had hoped I would be able to search on the special 'default' folder (retrieved using the `getDefaultFolder` method in `IMAPStore`), as this returns the root folder that contains all other folders. However although the retrieved `Folder` can provide a list of all available folders, it's type is not of type `HOLDS_MESSAGES`, and so it cannot be used for accessing or searching messages.

Is there another way to search messages over all folders, or will I be required to search each folder individually?

I'm afraid I can't post more than two hyperlinks, but here is access to the [Javamail com.sun.mail.imap documentation](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html), through which you can see information about the methods I've been describing.

Comment: I just found reference to the [ESEARCH command](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6237#section-3), which is an experimental IMAP command for searching across folders. Not sure if Javamail has support for this, though the mail server we are using does (Apache James).

Comment: I can't get the ESEARCH command to work properly - have asked a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683288/what-is-wrong-with-this-imap-esearch-command-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IMAP protocol doesn't provide this capability so JavaMail can't do any better than you can do yourself by iterating over all the folders and searching in each folder.

Comment: Javamail has no support for ESEARCH, so looks like I'm back to iterating over all. Thanks!