# What is wrong with this IMAP ESEARCH command syntax?

Tags: search, imap

I am looking for a way to search across all IMAP folders on my mail server. I recently discovered the [IMAP ESEARCH command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6237#section-2), which extends the usual SEARCH command to search across folders. I cannot, however, seem to make it work.

I have checked that the mail server supports `ESEARCH`. After telnet-ing in, I executed the following:

```
* OK JAMES IMAP4rev1 Server Server server-address is ready.
A1 LOGIN test test
A1 OK LOGIN completed.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY SASL-IR IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN CONDSTORE ESEARCH CHILDREN UIDPLUS UNSELECT WITHIN ENABLE I18NLEVEL=1 SEARCHRES IMAP4rev1 NAMESPACE QRESYNC
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
A3 LIST "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Sent"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Trash"
A3 OK LIST completed.
```

Note the presence of `ESEARCH`. I then tried the following `ESEARCH`, which fails.

```
A4 ESEARCH IN (mailboxes "INBOX") unseen
A4 BAD failed. Unknown command.
```

An ordinary search works fine:

```
A5 SELECT INBOX
* FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen)
...
A5 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
A6 SEARCH UNSEEN
* SEARCH 3
A6 OK SEARCH completed.
```

From what I can read of the spec and the [formal syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6237#section-4) this should work. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: That document indicates 'ESEARCH' is described by capability 'MULTISEARCH'.  Capability ESEARCH would be something else?

Comment: Ah you are right! I will have to contact the Apache James developers and see what happened to the supposed inclusion of [ESEARCH support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMAP-308). I wonder if that means it has ESEARCH response capability - I know some of the other search commands can return an ESEARCH response.

Comment: @Max if you convert that comment to an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document indicates `ESEARCH` is described by capability `MULTISEARCH`.

Capability `ESEARCH` might be something else?

Answer (score 3):

The `ESEARCH` capability indicates that the server supports [RFC 4731](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4731) and [RFC4466](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4466) which defined the `ESEARCH` reponse and an extended format of the `SEARCH` command.

The `MULTISEARCH` capability ([RFC 6237](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6237)) builds upon the `ESEARCH` capability to make it possible to search in another mailbox than the currently selected one. The command syntax you're using requires `MULTISEARCH`.